# AutoItX3 load error

Tags: ruby, rubygems, win32ole

i have some problem on AutoItX3 when i start script , script return unknown ole server

click.rb:

```
require 'win32ole'

WIN32OLE.new("AutoItX3.Control")
```

error:
[image]

also i follow up this [tutorial](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/207990)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the COM from AutoIt you first need to have the AutoItX3.dll and register it with regsvr32.
Install the program from their website https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/, cd to the folder where the AutoItX3.dll is present and run `regsvr32 AutoItX3.dll`
Alternatively you can `gem install` a gem that includes this dll, like eg Selenium or rautomation and again register that dll.